# How to display the exact error returned by firebase using Vuejs

Tags: firebase, vue.js

I have written this code to signup:

```js
    actions: {
    signup({ commit, dispatch }, formData) {
      axios
        .post('accounts:signUp?key=XXXXXXXXXXXX', {
          email: formData.email,
          password: formData.password,
          returnSecureToken: true
        })
        .then(res => {
          commit('userData', {
            token: res.data.idToken,
            userId: res.data.localId
          });
          dispatch('storeUserInfo', formData);
          console.log(res);
        })


         .catch(error => {
    alert(error.code);
              alert(error.message);
            });
        },
```

My aim is to display the exact error which is returned by Firebase like

> EMAIL_NOT_FOUND: There is no user record corresponding to this
>   identifier. The user may have been deleted. INVALID_PASSWORD: The
>   password is invalid or the user does not have a password.
>   USER_DISABLED: The user account has been disabled by an administrator

With this code every time it returns: `Request failed with status code 400` 
In the response I can see the message like:

```
   {
      "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND",
        "errors": [
          {
            "message": "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND",
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "invalid"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: @T.Short please refrain from formatting product names as code. If you're going to edit them, please fix their spelling, not their formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing

```
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error.response.data.error.message);
    });
```

You will be able to get the error message, e.g. "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND". It's then up to you to map it to the textual message (i.e. "There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.").

---

For more details, see the Axios documentation on Errors Handling: https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors

---

One extra note: The error messages you use as examples in your question don't correspond to `accounts:signUp` but to `accounts:signInWithPassword`